# How to configure jest with `ts-jest` to parse/transform projects in the `packages/` folder of a basic Turborepo project?

Tags: jestjs, vercel, ts-jest, turbo, turborepo

Has anybody here used ts-jest in the context of Turborepo?

My understanding for a standard Turborepo setup is that in general, the configs and common packages live in `/packages/*` (e.g. `/packages/jest-config`, but most of your apps will live in `/apps/`. My issue is that jest is running tests in `/packages/ui` just fine, but can't seem to transform/parse tests in `/apps/my-app` properly. Here's what my jest config looks like so far:

```js
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/test/__fixtures__',
    '<rootDir>/node_modules',
    '<rootDir>/dist',
  ],
  projects: [{
    displayName: 'ui',
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
    testMatch: ['<rootDir>/../ui/**/*.@(spec|test).ts?(x)'],
  },
  {
    displayName: 'my-app',
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
    testMatch: ['<rootDir>/../../apps/my-app/**/*.@(spec|test).ts?(x)'],
  }],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
};
```

Here's the folder structure to help clarify (and in case my `testMatch` settings are all wrong, and Turbo's cache is just letting me get away with it for the `packages/ui/` stuff, I only started adding them when troubleshooting the apps/ folder):

```
monorepo-root
├─ packages
│  ├─ ui/
│  │  └─ MyButton.text.tsx # passes
│  └─ jest-config/
│     └─ jest-preset.js
└─ apps/
   └─ my-app/
      └─ MyButton.text.tsx # fails
```

Pertinent parts of error:

```bash
FAIL my-app src/components/MyButton.test.tsx
 ● Test suite failed to run
   Jest encountered an unexpected token
   Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.
   ...
   Details:
   /Users/me/repos/monorepo-root/apps/my-app/src/components/MyButton.test.tsx:14
        (0, test_utils_1.render)(<MyButton_1.MyButton onClick={onClick}/>);
                                 ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (../../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1605:14)
```

Any help getting this working would be really appreciated! To summarize: tests in `/packages/ui` are working, identical tests in `/apps/my-app` are not. I'm not sure if this is a ts-jest issue or a Turborepo issue, but I'm hoping someone here has some experience with both. Thanks!

Comment: While curious what potential answers are, I ended up using `@swc/jest` instead

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/10356909/ben-wong Hey mate how did you set this up? I couldn't get `turbo run test` to work with any configuration. It's like jest config doesn't get picked up that way. I can get jest to run from the monorepo root against all packages, however that does not use turbo and misses out on caching.